# addEventListener JS подскажите как запушить выбранный элемент в чистый массив

Tags: javascript, события

```
   window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            if(e.target.className == "cell"){
                this.openCell(e.target)
            }
        }.bind(this))    

    }

    openCell(domElement){
        for(let i = 0; i<this.field.length; i++){
            if(this.field[i] == domElement){
                this.field[i].open()  // это метод экземпляра 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == "cell") { // в field 32 эелемента с классом cell
    this.openCell(e.target);
  }
}.bind(this));

function openCell(domElement) {
  let arrOpenElement = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.field.length; i++) {
    if (/*this.field[i] contains domElement*/) {
      arrOpenElement.push(this.field[i]); // вот тут хочу запушить тот элемент по которому кликаю
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arrOpenElement.length; i++) {
    let cur = arrOpenElement[i].cellElement();
    cur.open(); // для этого масиива элеменутам вызывается метод open() 
  }
}
```

Comment: вот поправил, проблема в том же что и была

Comment: Что "поправил"? Вы видите, что я добавил параметр в функцию `openCell`?

Comment: Как использовать этот domElement ? 
он не проходит проверки, и метод экземпляра не выполняется,я поменял исходник в теме.

Comment: Я же не знаю в каких отношениях в Вашем коде находятся `таргет клика` и `this.field[i]`.

Comment: спасибо за ответы)
дело было в отношениях)) разобрался)

Comment: не подскажешь как осилить js ?) 
просто пробовать писать прилажухи (типа 2048, калькуляторы и т.д) что б понять чистый js в идеале, а потом начать осваивать react. может знаешь годные книги или каналы на ютубе.